# Laptop stuck on boot with hard drive installed, cant access UEFI menu

Tags: boot, ssd, windows-11, uefi

whenever my SSD is installed in my laptop, all it shows is a black screen with the manufacture (Gigabyte) logo and some text for a split-second indicating some actions and their associated keys, but i cant get any of them to work. If i remove my hard drive, i can access the UEFI menu but cant get it to register the hard drive afterwards. I can also boot from USB, and currently have a flash drive setup with a Windows 11 installer, but I can not for the life of me figure out how to get said installer to work, as it never shows any drives or images.

I dont know what to do. My hard drive doesn't seem physically damaged, but it might be. It's detected as bootable media, so i doubt that's the case. If needed, i can probably get another hard drive, but i'd rather not spend the money on that

UPDATE:
I've found an old HDD, but would still like to recover my SSD. the HDD has windows 10 installed on it. Basically, all my problems boil down to: I cant have my SSD installed on boot, but i need my SSD to be detected. So i either need some way to prioritize another drive, (wasnt able to find anything for that in uefi settings) or somehow "refresh" my hard drives.

Comment: does the USB boot when the SSD is connected? not sure I understand what *it never shows any drives or images* even means? does the windows 11 installer run at all? what "images" are you expecting?

Comment: No, "...all it shows is a black screen with the manufacture (Gigabyte) logo and some text for a split-second..."
basically any menus where i am supposed to select something have no options.
Im gonna update the post with some new developments

Comment: If the computer behaves as you describe with the SSD but works normally with another drive then it's very likely that SSD is faulty. If you want to be really sure test it in another computer.

Comment: is it a SATA SSD or an M.2?